# omniauth-twitter gem not redirecting to twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, omniauth, omniauth-twitter

Hello i've run into a bit of a problem with the omniauth-twitter gem, i have followed the documentation to a t and when i go to localhost:3000/auth/twitter i get a no matching route error. I've googled this issue for hours to no avail, I've searched stack overflow to no avail, the only lead i managed to get was on issue on github which was answered with a link to a page which no longer exists all other "solutions" involved misconfiguring devise, which im not even using.

I literally only have the bare minimum code from the documentation that should at least redirect me to the twitter login.

Might this have something to do with the 3-legged oauth being enabled in my twitter app in the developer portal?

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Do I have a link to your GitHub repository?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:
The issue originates with the new CSRF protections due to Omniauth vulnerabilities, to use omniauth with rails for twitter you must use the
[omniauth-rails_csrf_protection gem by Cookpad](https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection)